# ArcGlobe .3dd file doesn't display

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d

Has anyone seen the following problem?

I've created a sample ArcGlobe application with Visual Studio - this obviously gives me the template where I should be able to launch the app.  Said application launches, I then go to load a .3DD File from the preexisting samples that come with ArcGIS.  I try loading the .3DD file, the APP hangs for a bit and eventually the Globe Control comes up.

When this happens, I see the World Physical Map (layer ) and the US Elevation (layer).  But the weird thing is is that the screen is black.  If I uncheck the layers, then I get a wireframe globe with no data displayed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you open the layers with an unmodified version of ArcGlobe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try looking at your internet blocking as I am sure that these layer come from arcgis online. Can you open a globe from the start menu?

new info...
I don't play with globe much. But here is what i found on the esri resources page...

> Data caching 
>   The GlobeDisplay object has a central role in managing and controlling tile generation and in the subsequent storing of data tiles for future use, called data caching. Data tiles are always stored in a memory cache and, optionally, in a disk cache. The main advantage of data caching is the improvement of visualization performance, as well as the reduction of repetitive data requests from data sources. The tile generator, IGlobeDisplayLayers.GenerateTiles, is used to preprocess data both in off-line mode, **called full caching**, and in an interactive on-demand mode, called on demand data caching.
>   Each data tile will be stored into memory and optionally onto disk for future use. Using data caching improves visualization performance. The ArcGlobe data caching structure is shown in the following diagram:

[image: tile caching]

> GlobeLayerProperties
>   The GlobeLayerProperties coclass is the layer extension that contains globe-specific layer properties, such as a layer drawing priority on the surface of the globe, exposed as IGlobeLayerProperties.BaseImageDrawingPriority. This value relates to the position of the layers that are part of the base globe (that is, draped layers and elevation layers) in the drawing order. To get an ordered list of layers in the base globe, use IGlobeDrawingOrder.OrderedLayers. 
>   Elevation layers are always on top of the ordered list followed by draped layers.
>   The GlobeLayerProperties object also controls the layer's cache data removal behavior via IGlobeLayerProperties.CacheRemovalOption. The default setting is the cache to be removed when exiting the application or removing the layer.

Comment: OK - let's say they are coming from arcgis online, but this machine does not have internet access.  what would my alternatives be?

Comment: in order to cache you might need to connect it at least once to get the static layers.

Comment: In Google Earth it was possible to get the cache data from one machine - copy it and then use it on another machine that never has internet access.  Is this something that can be done with ArcGIS?

Comment: i haven't ever tried it. they should both be looking in the same place for their cache though, so it is probably a reasonable hack idea.